# Why is Ajax.ActionLink updating entire page instead of just UpdateTarget

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

This should replace just the UpdateTarget, but it does not, it replaces the entire page and I don't see why.  The correct partial view is being returned, but instead of replacing the target id, it is replacing the entire page.

```
<div id="magHeader">
        <p>this is a test.</p>
        @Ajax.ActionLink("Edit", "GetEditor", "Home", new AjaxOptions(){ UpdateTargetId = "magHeader", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace})
</div>
```

At runtime, the link looks like this:

```
<a href="/Home/GetEditor" data-ajax-update="#magHeader" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax="true">Edit</a>
```

Is there something that I am doing wrong?  Have done this successfully in the past with no issues.

**Edit**
The underlying reason for this issue is that in VS 2012, you only needed to add a reference to the JQueryVal bundle to make this work.  However, in 2013, the BundleConfig.cs was changed so that the JQueryVal bundle no longer includes JQuery.Unobtrusive.  So the simple fix is to add it back into the bundle:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
```

Then all will work as expected.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check if you are loading `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")` into your page somewhere or not. It is probably because unobtrusive javascript file is not getting loaded. Check this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5xYjiFjrji8)

Edit:
Please check if you there packages installed in your packages.config file.

```
<package id="Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax" version="3.1.1" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net451" />
```

Comment: OK, so I watched the video and that is exactly the issue I am having. However, it is still not resolved.  Starting from a new fresh project in VS 13, I follow the steps in the video and make sure that jqueryval is included.  But the whole page is still replaced.  In FireFox, I can check the scripts tab and see that jqueryval is loaded as well as jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js.  So it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I checked and those packages were not installed.  So I installed them.  However, I still get the same result - the page is replace, not the id.

Comment: Is the signature of your controller method Public PartialViewResult and Returns PartialView("someview")

Comment: Note that when I do the same test with Visual Studio 2012, then it works exactly like you show in the video.  I just add a reference to JQueryVal and it works great.

Comment: Yes, the signature and return type are as specified.

Comment: OK, I tried a different way of including the unobtrusive-ajax and it worked that time! Thanks very much.

Comment: The difference between VS 12/13 is that in the 2013 project, the JqueryVal bundle no longer includes a reference to unobtrusive.  So you have to add it manually.

Answer (score 3):

This happens because of this main reason that your **jquery** script file and **jquery unobtrusive ajax** are not included on the main layout or child view, i am afraid that you are missing them,include the jquery,jquery unobtrusive ajax files in view and it will work like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Adding below script file reference worked.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
```