# Ajax.ActionLink replacing whole page

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

MVC4/VS2010/.Net4.0

I've found lots of answers around the net for Ajax.ActionLink() replacing the whole page rather than the UpdateTargetId, and most point to jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js.  I'm having a hard time getting my version to work with jquery.  Actually, I have it working without errors, but still seem to be getting the same behavior of posting to a new page.

I'm using jquery-2.1.1 and unobtrusive-ajax from here:
https://code.google.com/p/tfsstatus/

My PartialView X image to delete an image is created this way:

```
@Html.Raw(Ajax.ActionLink("[replacethis]", "DeletePhoto", 
                new
                {
                    PhotoId = photo.Id, 
                    UserId = photo.UserId, 
                    CurrentFolder = ViewData["CurrentFolder"], 
                    page = ViewData["PageNumber"]
                },
                new AjaxOptions()
                {
                    HttpMethod = "GET",
                    UpdateTargetId = "photoList",
                    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
                },
                new 
                {
                    style = "position:absolute;top:2px;right:2px;z-index:2;display:none;width:22px;height22px",
                    @class="deleteImg"
                }
            ).ToHtmlString().Replace("[replacethis]", 
            "<img src=\"/Content/Desktop/images/delete.png\" alt=\"Delete\"/>"))
```

I'm using Html.Raw() so that I can wrap an image instead of a text link and use replace on the text.

My Layout has the includes in the head:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

My Controller is laid out like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult DeletePhoto()
{
    // Code
    return PartialView("PhotoList", photos.ToPagedList(page, 24));
}
```

I was getting a javascript crash on 'live' because it is deprecated in the current JQuery.  So I changed each 'live' to 'on' within unobtrusive-ajax.

After lots of effort to get the versions synced on these two files, I'm still getting a new page instead of the partial updating in the target div after the clicking the X image.  Other than that, everything is working with the code, for example the image is being deleted as it should be.

Any help is appreciated.

[Additional Information]

My partial view looks like this:

```
@using MyProject.Areas.User.Models
@using PagedList.Mvc
@model PagedList.IPagedList<UserPhoto>

<div>
    @foreach (UserPhoto photo in Model)
    {
        <div id="id:@photo.Id" class="thumbnail photoThumb">
            <div style="position: relative; left: 0; top: 0;">
                <img src="/User/Photos/ImageThumbnail?PhotoId=@photo.Id&width=146&height=146" alt="photo"
                     width="146" height="146" style="position: relative; top: 0; left: 0;"/>
                @Html.Raw(Ajax.ActionLink("[replacethis]", "DeletePhoto", 
                    new
                    {
                        PhotoId = photo.Id, 
                        UserId = photo.UserId, 
                        CurrentFolder = ViewData["CurrentFolder"], 
                        page = ViewData["PageNumber"]
                    },
                    new AjaxOptions()
                    {
                        HttpMethod = "GET",
                        UpdateTargetId = "photoList",
                        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
                    },
                    new 
                    {
                        style = "position:absolute;top:2px;right:2px;z-index:2;display:none;width:22px;height22px",
                        @class="deleteImg"
                    }
                ).ToHtmlString().Replace("[replacethis]", 
                "<img src=\"/Content/Desktop/images/delete.png\" alt=\"Delete\"/>"))
             </div>  
        </div>
    }
    <div class="clear">
    </div>
</div>

@*  ****** Pagination ******  *@
<div style="width:100%;">
        @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page, UserId = ViewData["UserId"] }),
            new PagedListRenderOptions() { Display = PagedListDisplayMode.IfNeeded })
</div>
```

And my view calling the partial:

```
<div id="photoList">
    @{
        Html.RenderPartial("PhotoList", Model);
    }
</div>
```

I also tried to have the div photoList wrapper in the partial view with the same result.

[Additional Additional Information]

I made a new project to do the cliché 2 timestamp test to check if my jquery and unobtrusive-ajax worked.  You know the one, where you put a timestamp in the main view and then one in the updating partial view.  Well, that works.  So trying to narrow down the problem, I replaced everything in my main project's controller method that returns the partial view to just update a timestamp and commented out everything else in the partial view, and it still replaced the whole page with a page with nothing but the timestamp.

Comment: can you show your partial view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem after days of debugging.  I wasn't aware of how jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js worked.  My "X" image for deleting was over my photo.  So when I'd click the X I'd also get a click for the photo to preview it. In click override of the X I had event.stopPropagation() so that the underlying image would not get a click too.  This was preventing the click event that was overridden in jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js.  Once removing the stopPropagation call, the POSTS worked and the replace of the target div worked.

```
    $(".deleteImg").click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();  // This line was preventing it from working
        if (!confirm("Are you sure you wish to delete this photo?")) {
            return;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's try a couple of things.

1. I prefer to have `PartialViewResult` instead of `ActionResult` in the controller method even though VS doesn't complain.
2. `[HttpGet]` should not modify a resource. i.e. Since you are deleting a photo replace it with `[HttpPost]`.
3. Scripts - Also add the following scripts to layout page `jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js`.

Check this [post](http://mscodingblog.blogspot.com/2013/04/how-to-do-ajax-in-aspnet-mvc4.html) with sample code. Similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22616318/why-is-ajax-actionlink-updating-entire-page-instead-of-just-updatetarget/22616803#22616803).

Comment: 1. I have tried using PartialViewResult before, with no result, the reason I wasn't using it was I had an error callback at one point and was returning Json for errors, and couldn't with PartialViewResult.  However, I did change it at one point just to see, and it did the same thing.  2.  I originally had HttpPost but I got errors about Ajax.ActionLink wanting HttpGet.   3. I will add the validate js's and see.  My small test I mented in my update above didn't have those 2 and worked.

Comment: When I change to post, it gives me a 404-Not found. Oddly I can view the network traffic and even after clearing cache it posts the params in a query string and is using method GET, and of course doesn't find my HttpPost decorated function.  Adding the 2 validate js files didn't change anything.

Comment: Also, I've been to that page while trying to resolve the issue, the Microsoft jquery files are obsolete and no longer used.

Comment: True there is a different package you have to download. Microsoft.Jquery.Unobtrusive.Ajax and Microsoft.Jquery.Unobtrusive.Validation. Because of these files it is not sending POST. Fix things that is preventing POST but don't use GET for deleting.